# Ubuntu 16.04 does not consistently recognise my sd card

Tags: sd-card

I have problems having my Aspire 5730Z laptop recognize my sd card with Ubuntu 16.04 installed (I did not have this problem with 14.04).

I have used the following command to get it to work temporarily but I have to keep repeating this command and rebooting every time I want to use my sd card:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall udisks2
```

If anyone can help?

Comment: You can try according to this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072 .  It should work without reinstalling udisks2 or any other program package. But terminal commands are involved. If you need the same procedure several times, it is a good idea to put the command lines into a shellscript file and run the shellscript. -- Please notice that an SD card is sometimes seen as `/dev/mmcblk0` instead of `/dev/sdx` and use the correct device notation for the partitions in the command lines. (Check with `lsblk`)

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this behaviour on a Aspire E1 running Xenial 4.4.0-104-generic with high-capacity FAT32 cards (64GB). Those will not mount with

```
sudo mount -o rw,user,uid=1000,umask=007 /dev/mmcblk0 /media/user
```

and `gparted` shows an unallocated space.

Sometimes

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall udisks2
```

works, but not every time.